# Spark application is failing to build with spark-core jar 2.0.1

Tags: apache-spark, build.gradle

I am new to spark. I am trying to build spark with gradle where I am using as follows:

compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.10', version: '2.0.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.10', version: '2.0.1'

I am getting the following error:
error: object UserDefinedFunction is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql

```
[ant:scalac] import org.apache.spark.sql.UserDefinedFunction._
[ant:scalac]                             ^
[ant:scalac] error: bad symbolic reference. A signature in HiveContext.class refers to type Logging
[ant:scalac] in package org.apache.spark which is not available.
```

While the same code is building perfectly when I use jar 1.6 in my gradle build:

```
  compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.10', version: '1.6.0'
  compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.10', version: '1.6.0'
```

I extract the jar 2.0.1 and found that the function UserDefinedFunction is not available, while it is available in 1.6.

Please advice. How can I solve this issue and upgrade my codebase to jar 2.0.1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is expected. In Spark 2.0.0 use `org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction`:

- [SPARK-13296](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13296)
- https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/354d4c24be892271bd9a9eab6ceedfbc5d671c9c